# Circular arcs of angle less than $\pi$ form a semiring

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have trouble understanding this problem:

Verify that the circular arcs (including degenerate ones) of angle less than $\pi$ form a semiring; show that without this additional restriction the assertion is false.

It is an exercise from the book "Real Analysis: Measures, Integrals and Applications".

I tried to write circular arcs like intervals $[a,b]$ where $|b-a|<\pi=$ but it didn't turn out well. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the semiring operations supposed to be? If the problem doesn't specify somehow, it's not very well-formed...

Comment: @Micah: It’s a [semiring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets).

Comment: With which requirement(s) for a semiring are you having trouble?

Comment: I don't know how to define a circular arc, I guess the only way is [a,b) so that we have a semiring. But then again, I don't understand why the angles should be $< \pi$.

Comment: @user275181: Alternatively, you could allow all four types of arc, corresponding to intervals on the line like $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b]$, and $[a,b]$. The easiest way to describe them is in terms of the polar angles of their endpoints, though you have to be a bit careful with arcs that include angle $0$ or have it as an endpoint. \\ You should be able to see the reason for the $\pi$ restriction when you try to show that the intersection of two arcs is an arc.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott 
If we allow them to be like (a,b), shouldn't the restriction be $<=\pi$?

Comment: @user275181: You could allow it for the ones open at both ends, but you couldn’t allow it for any of the others, so you might as well still make the blanket restriction.

Comment: Ah, ok I get it now. You don't have to answer. Thank you again.